# Updating stacks

Tags: ros, installation, stacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you update individual stacks inside the installation directory(/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks)? Say I want to update the geometry stacks because of eigen compatibility with eigen3. I thought updating apt will suffice but it didn't.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9155/updating-stacks/) by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 475 on 2011-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running `sudo apt-get upgrade` will apply all bug fix updates.

However, `eigen3` is incompatible with the previous version, so it would not be appropriate to introduce that change in `cturtle`, which is already released and stable.

If you want the latest `eigen` interface, you should probably run `diamondback`, currently the [newest ROS distribution](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In released distributions such as cturtle, certain stacks (particularly those above 1.0.0 or for which major API-breaking changes have been made) will not be updated to the latest version. See http://www.ros.org/wiki/Distributions

For your particular issue, cturtle includes geometry 1.2 -- and I believe the eigen3 changes are found in 1.4 releases (which won't end up in cturtle).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-02-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2